# How to dynamically use switch case statement?

Tags: c++, vector, hash, set

I am mapping the RGB color to its unique gray value using hashmap. The number of colors can change based on input taken. so if input has 5 different color my output will be 0 for 1st color, 1 for 2nd color and so on.

I am using set for unique color identification but using for loop everytime for each color is very expensive. So I am looking for some kind of switch case solution which dynamically takes uniques values and map it instead of looping.
Here is snippit:

Step 1: Read a sample image like this
[image]

Step 2: Identify Unique colors ( I have done using std::set method). Now I have set with 4 values(like : Red: 255000000, Green : 000255000) etc. sample code for creating set with HashMaps that I used.

```
unsigned int hashMap(unsigned char B, unsigned char G, unsigned char R)
{
    unsigned int val = B * 1000000 + G * 1000 + R;
    return val;
}

int main()
{ 
  std::set<unsigned int> uniqueColors;
  uniqueColors.insert(hashMap(255,0,0));
}
```

Step 3: Now I want to give unique colors a unique label like ( Red=3, Green=2 etc) for a seprate Image and default 0 to others. i.e. [image: Sample Image]

Step 4. For previous step one method is to create a array/vector and assign a unique labels corresponding to that color. Problem with this method is that for each pixel I have to look into whole array/vector so the operation is quite expensive.  So i am looking a faster solution to this. I can't use HashTable due to memory constrain. 
Step 5: I dont know wheather a switch case will be faster or not but It will be faster then searching through array.

So any faster solution will help me alot. Thanks hope the queston is clear now.

Comment: Perhaps you should write a code generator which emits the switch statement you need?

Comment: Do not be tricked by the switch statement syntax. It still internally makes a linear number of comparisons until it finds the right match. It just looks nicer and makes some optimizations more straightforward.

Comment: @jszpilewski The code generated for a switch statement is rarely "linear". The compiler will use a multitude of methods, including indexed jump tables and binary tree like comparisons to quickly locate the correct code.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ok, I should have used a 'non-constant' expression instead but anyway fitting a switch statement should not be an algorithm design goal. Probably it is better to provide an explicit binary search routine when needed.

Comment: @JohnZwinck , jszpilewski , 1201ProgramAlarm I have repharased question. I have to iterate through 50,000 x 50,000 dimension images so some faster algorithm will help me alot.